# how to get a single column vector from 2 consecutive for loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I m trying to get a single column vector that is the monthly averages of my X values for each year (10 years). I am using 2 consecutive for loop - and perhaps a simpler code will get me the monthly average for each year...?

Ok - so here is my matlab code:

```
   X = values;
   t = time values;
   timevec = datevec(t);
   years = timevec(:,1) ;
   yy = unique(years);
   month = timevec(:,2);
   mm = unique(month);

   for iyear = 1:length(yy);
         fy = find(years==yy(iyear));
         ym = month(fy);

        for imonth = 1:length(mm);
                fm = find(ym==mm(imonth));
                Xmean(imonth,iyear) = mean(X(fm));
         end
    end
```

However, I would like to get a single column vector and not a matrix of size (length(imonth),length(iyear))  - so something like:

```
     Xmean(:) of size ((length(imonth*iyear)), 1)
```

does this make sense? I would be grateful if you could help me in this problem.

Cheers,
S.

Comment: What's wrong with Xmean(:)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with custom function `@mean`.

```
[~,~,yi] = unique( timevec(:,1) ); % year index, using unique to start with one.
mi = timevec(:,2); % month index
subs = 12*(yi-1) + mi; % month-year into a single vector index
Xmean = accumarray( subs(:), X(:), [], @mean );
Xmean(isnan(Xmean)) = 0; % remove mean([]) results.
```

Comment: Thanks very much but I do not get what does the subs is?

Comment: Ok - I get some nan in my data set - so how do I deal with that? sorry but I m not so used of this accumarray.

Comment: You get `NaN` because you have months with no data: `mean([])` returns `NaN`. see my edit.

Comment: Ok - sorry for annoying you guys - but while it seems to work all good, I have some issues - and not sure why does that happen. The first 12 values of Xmean are '0' and this independently of having 'nan'. Could you please let me know why does this happen? Thanks in advance!!